# C# serial input - formatting

Tags: c#, serial-port, formatting

I'm using C# and the serial port to collect data from a GSM module. 
For this I connect to the GSM unit and send AT commands to retrieve any SMS that are present.

I believe I have connected successfully, I believe my issue is with the format of the return data - as seen below this consists of multiple CR's and LF's -- so far I have tried:

```
                serialPort.WriteLine("AT+CMGL=\"ALL\"");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

                while (true)
                {
                    Telemetry += serialPort.ReadLine();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Telemetry);
                }
                //bool ReadTelemetry = true;
                //while( ReadTelemetry )
                //{
                //    Telemetry = serialPort.ReadExisting();
                //    if (Telemetry.Contains("OK"))
                //        ReadTelemetry = false;
                //}
```

Though unsure I think the problem is the method of reading data; ReadLine or ReadExisting.
What can be done to read this format into an array?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused as to what your problem is? Do you get the data back okay but just need it putting into a more sensible format or do you have trouble getting the data you have screenshotted?

Comment: Sorry dav_i, I should have been clear - I don't receive any data, only blank lines. The data shown in the screen shot is from realTerm connected to the GSM module

Comment: Have you confirmed that you have connected to the device successfully using your `serialPort` object?

Comment: Yes, I see wht you mean and yes I believe I have connected successfully, as in correct COM port and Baud rate:          serialPort= new SerialPort(COMbox.Text, Convert.ToInt32(BAUDbox.Text))

Comment: Of interest, how may I test a successful connection?

Comment: Hmm.. maybe try putting a `Sleep (500)` in your loop? (p.s. I do hope you are using threads here!)

Comment: It is *very* unlikely that the output was produced by the code snippet.  Getting them to agree is pretty essential to get a decent answer.

Comment: Yes thanks Hans - this is right, the image output is from REALTERM I do state this above. The code snipped does not generate anything.

Comment: Davi_i, in response; I'm not using threads here - do you think this could be the issue and sleep(500) didn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: I am not sure if would make sense to put the data as they are in array. I would first of all strip out all the empty lines and filter the line of interest using the headers. Thereafter using substrings  I would get out the interesting part of each line and then transfer only those parts to an array for the subsequent use of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a datareceived handler for the serial port? If you do, you can add all the received characters to a FIFO (FirstInFirstOut) queue which is thread-safe. Then in the main program, read the characters from the queue and handle them as per your logic.

I posted an example here: [Serial port reading + Threads or something better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335690/serial-port-reading-threads-or-something-better/16345503#16345503)