# How to capture the SerialPort DataReceived entire string to Global Variable?

Tags: c#, string, serial-port

I'm currently working with 4 devices:

- 1 Flow Meter
- 3 Particle Counter
- 1 Analog/Digital Converter
- and 1 USB/RS485 Converter.

The Flow Meter is connected to Analog/Digital Converter; Analog/Digital Converter and the 3 Particle Counter is connected to USB/RS485 Converter.
I've using serialPort1 and written a small method to read the SerialPort.

The SerialPort being read!

But unfortunately, I need to separate the string the get Particles Counters.
The devices send the string in this format: ?01,00000,00000,00000,n/a,n/a
I try to capture the string to separate in the commas, however so capture the end of the string or "n/a".

**How to capture the entire string to variable and treat this variable in another method?**

My method:

```
private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
if(serialPort1.DataBits==8)
    {
    RxString=serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
    }
}

private void DisplayText(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
}
```

Comment: Why do you test for serialport1.databits? When you get data in the serialport buffer, you can use a stringbuilder object to build the string, then parse the string for the data. Or use a threadsafe FIFO queue and add the received characters as they arrive right into the queue, then dequeue the characters in a function, not worrying about locking. An example is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335690/serial-port-reading-threads-or-something-better/16345503#16345503

Comment: I did tests with the code of the link that you gave me.
We have activity on the serial port and to see the leds the USB/RS485 converter.
However the data does not appear in textBox. while (serialDataQueue.TryDequeue(out ch))
        {
            // do something with ch, add it to a textbox 
            // for example to see that it actually works
            textboxDataReceived.Text += ch;
        } 
Put a breakpoint inside private void readSearialDataQueue(){}. Not the flow passes through here. If flow is not here, not will release data on textboxDataReceived.

Comment: have you checked that the received data is indeed added to the queue? Maybe a breakpoint in the datareceived handler will show that. And as always, showing your code will ensure more people responding.

Comment: I put the code in this new Question, please.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204353/how-to-optimeze-the-mount-array-from-serialport1-readexisting-in-c-sharp